# How to save the output of a sliced array as separate items rather than a string, when set as a var?

Tags: bash, array

When slicing an array the output is captured in a variable as a string.

When the slice is used directly it will be separate items.

How can I save a sliced array in a variable without it being turned into a string?

Any other method or way to go about this?

#### Example:

```bash
# setting IFS to this, no need to quote anything
IFS=$'\n'

mapfile -t arr < <(for i in {1..6}; do echo $i; done)

declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="4" [4]="5" [5]="6")

# $() or `` give the same results  
slc=`echo ${arr[@]:0:3}`  

# proving that when the slice is saved as a var, it's a string
for i in $slc; do echo $i; done
1 2 3

# proving that when the slice is used directly the items are separate
for i in ${arr[@]:0:3}; do echo $i; done
1
2
3
```

#### Got it working with the accepted answer, note; with or without quotes when `IFS=$'\n'` the results are the same:

```bash
IFS=$'\n'

slc=(${arr[@]:0:3})

for i in ${slc[@]}; do echo $i; done
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In:

> ```
> echo ${arr[@]:0:3}
> ```

First, you forgot the quotes which means the expansion is subject to split+glob (with `IFS=$'\n'`, that's still splitting on newline, and that's still doing globbing), and used `echo` which cannot be used for arbitrary data.

`echo` is being passed several arguments (the elements of the slice further subjected to split+glob), and it prints them space-separated.

With:

> ```
> var=`echo...`
> ```

(btw, that's the old deprecated form of command substitution, you should use `var=$(echo...)` instead)

the shell collects that output (minus the trailing newline characters) into a *scalar* variable as that's scalar variable assignment syntax, but anyway the information about where each element starts and ends has long been lost since `echo` bundled everything into one stream.

To store the slice into a variable, you need an array variable and use the array assignment syntax:

```
$ arr=( '*' $'\n' '' 'element '{4..6} ) # ¹
$ slc=( "${arr[@]:0:3}" )
$ typeset -p arr slc
declare -a arr=([0]="*" [1]=$'\n' [2]="" [3]="element 4" [4]="element 5" [5]="element 6")
declare -a slc=([0]="*" [1]=$'\n' [2]="")
```

Same as you'd do:

```
   @slc = @arr[0..2]         # in perl
    slc = $arr( `{seq 3} )   # in rc
set slc   $arr[1..3]         # in fish
    slc=( "${arr[1,3]}" )    # in yash
    slc=( "${(@)arr[1,3]}" ) # in zsh
```

And to loop over the elements:

```
for i in "${slc[@]}"; do
  something with "$i"
done
```

---

<sup>¹ or `readarray -td '' arr < <(printf '%s\0' '*' $'\n' '' 'element '{4..6}` if you have to use `readarray` or its misnomer `mapfile` alias, relying on the fact that bash variables or builtin arguments cannot contain NUL characters anyway.</sup>

Comment: thank you, I try to avoid assigning vars using `echo` this way makes much more sense, btw I tried everything with quotes and the result was the same, this worked for me `slc=(${arr[@]:0:3})`

Comment: @Nickotine, `slc=(${arr[@]:0:3})` invokes split+glob which doesn't make sense whatsoever here. See also [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346) and [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694) for instance for details.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll quote if I have to write bash scripts on a collaboration or work situation.